# Centos 7 server won't boot - 'Dependency failed for Network Manager Wait Online'

Tags: systemd, networkmanager, rescuemode

I have a Centos 7 server that won't boot, it's giving me the following errors[image]

I can boot to single user mode but I just get the following when I try to query any of these services with systemctl

`systemctl status polkit
Unit polkit.service could not be found.`

Any ideas what could be causing the boot issues or what the best way to troubleshoot this is?

Comment: Please add the output of `dmesg` and `cat /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: I only have a console session with no networking so I have no way to get that data from the host. I can go looking for anything specific. The issues I'm having trying to use systemctl in single user mode aren't specific to this host, I get the same thing on a working test server if I boot that to single user mode.Iif anyone can explain why that is and how to amend service configuration, i.e. startup and dependencies from single user mode I'd appreciate it.